# getting the outlook mail's latest status(replied or forwarded)

Tags: vba, outlook

I am working on an automation on mails in outlook VBA. I want to use  **PR_VERB_EXECUTION_TIME** property to get the latest status of mail and check whether the  mail has already been replied or forwarded and send mail if the mail is unattended. Any help in

```
Sub Test(Item AS MailItem)
//Item is my incoming mail
Dim Obj As Outlook.MailItem
Dim str As String
Dim propaccessor As Outlook.Propertyaccessor
Set propaccessor = Item.propertyAccessor

str = propaccessor.Getproperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10820040")

'Str value is setting to null due to which error is thrown
'but other properties are working fine
'i want to use this string and compare current time and then reply if it is equal to current time

End Sub
```

how to use the property is appreciated!.

Comment: what have you tried so far? Check the [help] and [ask] for tips on improving the quality of your question. Consider adding an [mcve] which illustrates what you've tried so far along with an explanation of your specific problems/errors.

Comment: PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTED will always be 0 and PR_VERB_EXECUTION_TIME will always be null on incoming mail. These properties are for mail where you have replied.

Comment: thanks for the info niton. But how can i make this check on incoming mail whether someone replied to it. This case comes when i receive mails with a delay from the server when i open my outlook so i have to avoid replying to a mail which has already been replied

Answer (score 2):

for that you need to use `PropertyAccessor.GetProperty` Method

```
    For Each mailItem In mailitems
     If mailItem.Class <> olMail Then Exit For
     Set propertyAccessor = mailItem.propertyAccessor
     LastVerbExecuted = CheckBlankFields("PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTED", propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10810003"))
     Select Case LastVerbExecuted
       Case Last_Verb_Reply_All, Last_Verb_Reply_Sender, Last_Verb_Reply_Forward
          Subject = mailItem.Subject
          'This appears to be local time
          RecievedTime = mailItem.ReceivedTime
          'This appears to be GMT
          strRepliedTime = CheckBlankFields("PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTION_TIME", propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10820040"))
          OriginalAuthor = mailItem.Sender
          'Replier = ...
          If strRepliedTime <> "" Then
            'Convert string strRepliedTime to time format here...using a custom function
          End If
          LogData Subject, OriginalAuthor, Replier, RecievedTime, RepliedTime
       Case Else
         'in case you want to do something here
     End Select
   Next mailItem
```

Refer http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1739523

you can do this way

```
        Const Last_Verb_Reply_All = 103
    Const Last_Verb_Reply_Sender = 102
    Const Last_Verb_Reply_Forward = 104
    For Each mailItem In mailitems
     If mailItem.Class <> olMail Then Exit For
     Set propertyAccessor = mailItem.propertyAccessor
     LastVerbExecuted = CheckBlankFields("PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTED", propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10810003"))
     Select Case LastVerbExecuted
       Case Last_Verb_Reply_All, Last_Verb_Reply_Sender, Last_Verb_Reply_Forward
            'it means email already responded   
            exit sub
            'i dont think there is need to check time
          'strRepliedTime = CheckBlankFields("PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTION_TIME", propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10820040"))
       Case Else
         'in case you want to do something here
     End Select
    Next mailItem
```

Comment: Thanks Maddy but my exact scenario is like i have a script which replies to mails as soon as it arrives in my inbox now, since it is a client script it wont run if i turn off my outlook. So when i turn on again after few hours in the mean time if there are any mails and someone has already replied to those mails, my script is not checking it and it is replying again. so,i want to apply the lastexecutedtime logic in my incoming mail irrespective of when it arrives to my mailbox.

Comment: @dinesh ..can you please update your question with sample code? so i can further analyse

Comment: @dinesh..one solution can be that you can disable script before closing the Outlook and whenever you start outlook first read all emails and after that enable the script

Comment: Yes right now i am disabling it manually before closing the outlook. But, in worst case scenarios it will create problems so thought of writing this logic. i will share the code shortly

Comment: am not able to see your code. please update it in your question

Comment: Thanks maddy but the above code checks all the mails? if yes i want only for my incoming mail. Also,i have a doubt as i mentioned earlier my string is setting to null value so what will be the format of result if i use LAST_VERB_EXECUTED?

Comment: PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTED property documented in 
http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/D/D/5DD33FDF-91F5-496D-9884-0A0B0EE698BB/%5BMS-OXOMSG%5D.pdf   please use a Mapi editor like Outlook Spy or MFCMAPI